# Add events in viewRender fullcalendar

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, fullcalendar

how can i add new events using URL in `viewRender`?

```
viewRender: function(view, element){

}
```

how can i add events using a URL?

i want to do something like this?:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/get-events.php',
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    success: function (events) {
        console.log(events);
    },
    fail: function() {
        alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
    }
});
```

and i want to add the events in my calendar. how can i do that?

Comment: why do you want to do this? If you specify an events feed via this method: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ or via custom function that updates events based on date: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ then whenever the view is rendered and/or the date is changed then the events will be refreshed automatically anyway. No need to do anything during the viewRender event.

Comment: @ADyson i'm trying to show only the events on the user month. so when user changes month (`viewRender`), i want it to `get-events.php` to fetch that month's events. any idea how to do this?

Comment: yes, by using the methods I suggested above. If you read the "events json feed" article, it explains to you that fullCalendar automatically passes "start" and "end" variables to the server whenever it calls the server method (get-events.php in your case). It does this every time the view or the date is changed, so that you can return the correct data for that time period.

Comment: @ADyson yes that what I need when I put it inside my viewRender, it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: because that's not what you do with it. It's an option you supply to the calendar when setting up, e.g. `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ events: "events.php", //...etc`. If you'd read that article https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ properly it shows you a very clear simple example of how to use it. Like I said, get rid of your viewRender and stop thinking about it, you don't need it for this task.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I know. I already have it when i set up my calendar. I'm using  `viewRender` because when my calendar shows up, I'm only loading the current month's events. When the user switches months, `viewRender` gets called and i need to populate my calendar with events via the url: `get-events.php?month=blahblahblah`

Comment: no, you don't need viewRender for this. you have not understood my comments. If you define your events feed as per the instructions here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ so that it accepts "start" and "end" dates (instead of just a "month" parameter) then fullCalendar will refresh the events for you **automatically** when the month changes, without writing any extra code. This will also work for the week and day views automatically too. You are making this more complicated than you need to. Try it and see. If you can't make it work then post your JS and PHP here